# Как ввести строку заданного размера

Tags: c++

У меня есть символьная строка. Мне нужно с клавиатуры ввести в нее значение, не превышающее 10 символов. При вводе 11 символа функция, которая считывает с клавиатуры эти символы должна завершится.
Как можно организовать такой ввод, есть ли встроенная функция или нужно просто в цикле считать кол-во введенных символов и сравнивать их с необходимым размером?
Спасибо!

Comment: Почему бы вам просто не обрезать введенную строку? В чем заключается проблема, что пользователь должен ввести именно 10 знаков?

Comment: [Читайте доки, они рулез](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/). Правда, при вводе большего кол-ва символов она не завершится, но в строку не попадёт больше нужного.

Comment: Входная строка ограничена пробелом или только 10 символами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, формально можно поступить примерно так:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char input[11];
    memset(input,0,11);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        input[i] = getch();
        putchar(input[i]);
        if (input[i] == '\r')
        {
            input[i] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\nInput: [%s]\n",input);
}
```

Но при этом пользователь лишен возможности исправления своего ввода (например, использовать backspace). Так что подумайте - может, имеет смысл или просто считывать длинную строку и обрезать ее потом, или считывать не более 10 символов -

```
char input[11];
fgets(input,10,stdin);
printf("\nInput: [%s]\n",input);
```

(с обрезкой последнего '\n' для более короткой строки, если это важно).

Comment: он лишен только в этом случае. можно ведь сделать управление switch(ch)... 8 - backspace, i=i?i--:0... или по-другому

Comment: @J.Doe Если человек спрашивает, как это сделать вообще - вряд ли он напишет такое редактирование строки - тем более что надо соответствующим образом отображать исправления на экране...